# Get a list of all activities

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, activities

Journeys have activities, I need to get list of all activities through API or some other way. I found /v1/interactions/{{journeyId}} but it is not suitable for my task!

I found also that there is an opportunity to get a list of all journey /interaction/v1/interactions, but is there such a method for the activities ?

Comment: is this as in, all activities ever across all Journeys in your BU, or just the activities from a single Journey?

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQL query and `_JourneyActivity` [data view](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_as_data_view_journey_activity.htm&type=5) to get the journeys activities. Try something like this:

```SQL
SELECT
      journeyActivity.ActivityName
    , journeyActivity.ActivityType
FROM _JourneyActivity AS journeyActivity
INNER JOIN
_Journey AS journey
ON
journeyActivity.VersionID = journey.VersionID
WHERE
journey.JourneyID = 'Your Journey ID '
AND
journey.VersionNumber = 'Your Journey VersionNumber'
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you asked about API first, this answer will be API related.

Both endpoints that you mentioned give you the option to also return activities - you just need to include an optional `extras` parameter (which is mentioned in the official documentation of both routes).

This parameter accepts the following values:

- `activities`
- `outcome`
- `stats`
- `all` - this allows the contents of all above parameters to be returned

You wanted activities only, so you can just add `?extras=activities` to the base endpoint URLs resulting in something like this:

- `GET /interaction/v1/interactions?extras=activities` [(documentation)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/getInteractionCollection.html)
- `GET /interaction/v1/interactions/{id}?extras=activities` [(documentation)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/getInteractionById.html)